# Pytorch/Ktrain import name BartForConditionalGeneration from transformers error?

Tags: pytorch, python-import

I am trying to use the package ktrain's text function

```
 text.TransformerSummarizer()
```

However, when I try to use it I get the error that

```
 TransformerSummarizer() requires PyTorch to be installed.
```

I installed PyTorch using different variations of conda and pip, as well as the command given on the pytorch website. After it installs and I try to use it I get:

```
from ktrain import text
import torch
from transformers import BartForConditionalGeneration

ts = text.TransformerSummarizer()
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BartForConditionalGeneration' from 'transformers' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py)
```

Any suggestions of how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: What version is your `transformers`? Can you try updating it?